# Unity game stats saving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help to define API for managing game data.

For example:

```
  Person john = new Person
{
    Id = 1234,
    Name = "John Doe",
    Email = "jdoe@example.com",
    Phones = { new Person.Types.PhoneNumber { Number = "555-4321", Type = Person.Types.PhoneType.HOME } }
};
```

I would like to be able to save data to different storage mediums:
Unity's PlayerPrefs, in-memory, storing to file, protobuf.

And it shouldn't require any changes to the code that use this API.

Comment: So where is the question?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what the API in this case?

Comment: Your post is very unclear and doesn't even have a proper question. What is it you are trying to achieve, and what is this API you are refering to? If you can expand your question maybe we can help. A more detailed opst on how to ask a proper question can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to save the data would be to serialize it all into a JSON string, which then you can save either to Unity's PlayerPrefs, a file or even store it on an external server.

There are several plugins you can use that are available for free (or you can even use the built-in Unity serialization as long as your data does not have any nested arrays).

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347

https://assetstore.unity.com/search?q=json&k=json

All the best,

The Knights of Unity

Comment: for nested arrays and built-in Unity serialization you just need to create an object that contain an array and serialize that object. basically you have a serialized class with an array of Something, and Something contain another array of SomethingElse (iterate until you can serialize a basic type like a string).